# How do I print values of list?

Tags: python

I have a python question:

Suppose you are given a vector, `x`, containing real values that are mostly zero. For instance:

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Complete the function, `compress_vector(x)`, so that returns a dictionary `d` with two keys, `d['inds']` and `d['vals']`, which are lists that indicate the position and value of all the non-zero entries of `x`. For the previous example,

```
d['inds'] = [1, 5, 6, 9]
d['vals'] = [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.10]
```

Note 1. Your implementation must not modify the input vector `x`.

Note 2. If `x` contains only zero entries, `d['inds']` and `d['vals']` should be empty lists.

I was able to print the indices, but I'm not sure how to print the values.

```
def compress_vector(x):
    assert type(x) is list
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}

    d = ([i for i, e in enumerate(x) if e != 0], )
    return d
```

Comment: Add it to a tuple? `d = ([(i,e) for i, e in enumerate(x) if e != 0], )`

Comment: 1. This isn't about printing. 2. You initialise d but then don't use it and overwrite it. 3. You're creating d as a tuple instead of a dictionary. 4. If you understood how you got the indices it should be trivial for you to change that piece of code slightly to get the values (e) instead.

Comment: `dict(zip(*[('index','vals'),zip(*[(i,j )for i,j in enumerate(x) if j!=0])]))`

Comment: `dict(zip(('index','vals'),zip(*filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0,enumerate(x)))))`

Answer (score 4):

You can define this function as follows:

```
def compress_vector(x):
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}

    for i, e in enumerate(x):
        if e != 0:
            d['inds'].append(i)
            d['vals'].append(e)
    return d
```

Basically, you create a `dict` which values for `'inds'` and `'vals'` are initialized to the empty list. Then, you iterate the list using `enumerate` in order to have the index (`i`) and the element (`e`). Inside the loop, you put the condition that the element should non-zero, and append `i` and `e` to the previous lists.

Comment: why not keeping `d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, please let me steal your line to remove 3 of mi lines.

Comment: @JoeIddon, thanks for your suggestion. I totally missed it.

Comment: No problem! This is definitely the most clear way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. Let's look at one part of your code:

```
i, e in enumerate(x)
```

Here `e` is the value from the list `x` and `i` is the index. So you can modify the list comprehension to

```
[e for i, e in enumerate(x) if e != 0]
 ^
```

Note that since this doesn't need the index, you can get rid of the `enumerate()` call:

```
[e for e in x if e != 0]
```

You still need to make some modifications to store the two lists into a dictionary.

Comment: Correct although of course it's actually useless to use `enumerate` in this case because you're doing nothing with `i`, and as this is clearly an educational question I think OP should be encouraged to do it in a sensible way.

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the zeroes from an enumerated `x` and then use a dict-comprehension to extract the two elements from each tuple.

```
def compress_vector(x):
    enumed = [(i,n) for i,n in enumerate(x) if n]
    return {k:[e[i] for e in enumed] for i,k in enumerate(('inds','vals'))}
```

and a test:

```
>>> compress_vector(x)
{'inds': [1, 5, 6, 9], 'vals': [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.1]}
```

Comment: A variation of this solution with `zip()`: `zipped = zip(**enumed)` and then extract the two lists into a dictionary: `return {'inds': zipped[0], 'vals': zipped[1]}`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thought that would be too neat! `enumed` is not a dict, so we can't use the `**` notation...

Comment: My mistake. It should be `zipped = zip(*enumed)`. Use `*` to explode a list as arguments or use `**` to explode a dict as keywoard args.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]

def compress_vector(x):
    d = {'inds': [], 'vals': []}
    for i, val in enumerate(x):
        if val != 0.0:
            d['inds'].append(i)
            d['vals'].append(val)

    return d

d = compress_vector(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is that you are assigning a tuple object to the dictionary object. Notice:

```
d = ([i for i, e in enumerate(x) if e != 0], )
```

The enclosing braces for the list comprehension make it a tuple. So you can't get`d` to have this required represention:

```
d['inds'] = [1, 5, 6, 9]
d['vals'] = [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.10]
```

You must explicitly append the values that satisfy the criteria to lists.

```
def compress_vector(x):
    d = dict()
    d['inds'] = []
    d['vals'] = []
    for i, e in enumerate(x):
        if e != 0:
            d['inds'].append(i)
            d['vals'].append(e)
    return d
```

If there are no non-zero values they won't be appended to the lists and you will get a dictionary with empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

**Soloution**

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]
d = {"inds" : [], "vals" : []}

for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] != 0:
        d["inds"].append(i)
        d["vals"].append(x[i])

for k, v in d.items():
        print(str(k) + ": " + str(v))
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/12/alien_invasion_2$ python3 help_print_value_list.py 
> vals: [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.1]
> inds: [1, 5, 6, 9]
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/12/alien_invasion_2$
> ```

**Comments**

Just created some loops with conditions, if you have questions, comment.

Also this piece of code will help you match your "inds" to "vals" if ever needed, you can manipulate it as you like but just to get the idea through:

```
for i in range(len(d["inds"])):
    print(str(d["inds"][i]) + ": " + str(d["vals"][i]))
```

This outputs:

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/12/alien_invasion_2$ python3 something.py 
> 1: 0.87
> 5: 0.32
> 6: 0.46
> 9: 0.1
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/pcc/12/alien_invasion_2$
> ```